# how the Transaction concept is implemented in EJB

Tags: java, transactions, jakarta-ee, ejb

I wan to know how the transaction is internally implemented in EJB. I want to know the logic they use to create a transaction. if you could point out some articles that would be helpful

Answer (score 8):

Hibernate doesn't *implement* transactions, it relies on and wraps JDBC transactions or JTA transactions (either container managed or application managed).

Regarding EJBs, if you want to understand the details of a JTA Transaction Manager, you'll need to be fluent with the JTA interfaces `UserTransaction`, `TransactionManager`, and `XAResource` which are described in the [JTA specification](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/tech/jta-138684.html). The [JDBC API Tutorial and Reference, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jdbc/) will also be useful to understand the XA part of a JDBC driver.

Then, get the sources of an EJB container (like JBoss) or of a standalone JTA Transaction Manager (like Atomikos) to analyze the TM part. And good luck.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I was talking about the Transaction implementation in the EJB or any JTA implementation.

Comment: i am extremely sorry , there is an javascript error in my browser.i have upvoted for your answer.

Comment: @Suresh Well, no problem. But I must admit that I was surprised because 1. there is nothing wrong with my answer 2. I find it harsh to downvote answers on your own questions. Feel free to revert it if it was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

This question could have answers at many levels.

A general discussion of what's going on can be found [here](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html)

My summary goes like this ... First, somewhere there must be a transaction coordinator, the EJB container will know about the coordinator - typically that's part of the application server. So all the EJB container has to do is to call

```
someobject.BeginTransaction()
```

that's it. The actual API the EJB container uses is [JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API). EJBs can actually use Bean Managed transaction transaction or Container managed transactions. In the Bean Managed case the implementer nhas to make the JTA calls. More usually we use Container Managed transactions (CMT). In which case the container has logic which is run before the implementation is reached. For example:

```
if ( we're not already in a transaction )
    begin transaction

call the EJB implementation
```

and later the container has logic

```
if ( finished processing request )
    commit transaction
```

with other paths to abort the transaction if errors have happened.

Now that logic is more complex because CMT EJBs are annotated with transaction control statements. For example you can say things "if we already have a transaction, use it" So if one EJB calls another only a single transaction is used. Read up the EJB spec for that.

However all that's pretty obvious in any write-up of Java EE EJBs. So I suspect that you're asking moe about what happens **inside** the JTA calls, how the transaction manager is implemented and its relationship to the transactional resource managers (eg. Databases). That's a huge topic. You've actually go implementations of the [XA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing_monitor) distributed transaction protocol down there. Frankly I doubt that you really need to need to know this. At some point you have trust the APIs you're using. However there is one key detail: your Transaction Manager (typically the App Server itself) must be able to tell the REsource Managers the fate of any given transaction, and that information must survive restart of the App Server, hence some persistent store of transaction information must be kept. You will find transaction logs somewhere, and in setting up the App Server you need to make sure those logs are well looked after.

Comment: +1 for mentioning XA, as its the usual base protocol for J2EE transaction services. It should also be noted that JTA is an interface specification -- its up to someone else (Wbelogic, Websphere, Oracle, JBOSS etc. etc.) to provide the actual implementation.

Comment: Is "the implementor" the JTS? As i read over the net, JTA is "specification" like JDBC API's (analogy). In context of JTA, i have read two terms: JTA, JTS, so is JTS the implementation of JTA?

Comment: No, JTS is concerned with some implementation details under JTA, Strictly speaking a JTA implementation might not use JTS, JEE specs recommend but don't mandate the use of JTS. JTS is an implementation for the CORBA Transaction spec OTS and is concerned with the communications between resource managers and transaction managers. Clearly if the JTA implementation uses JTS then it's likely to find other resource managers that speak that protocol, hence the reason JEE recommends its use.

Comment: @djna thanks for the info. Then who does implement JTA? Is it container in case of EJB? What about Spring Framework? I read that Spring too uses JTA for distributed/global transactions. I am getting confused over this (many inter-related terminologies)

Comment: The container vendor typically implements this. I worked with the people who wrote the transaction engine inside WebSphere - these guys really understand that stuff. I don't know enough about Spring to know how much it does itself. In simple cases where you don't need distributed transactions things are relatively simple. I believe that spring allows you to plug a vendors (JTA complient) transaction engine and for example JBoss has indstructions onn how to do that. https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossTransactionsWithSpring

Answer (score 2):

From [EJB in Action](http://www.manning.com/panda/) book

> The protocol commonly used to achieve multiple resource is the **two-phase commit**. The two-phase commit protocol performs an additional preparatory step before the final commit. **Each resource manager involved** *is asked if the current transaction can be successfully committed*. If any of the resource managers indicate that the transaction cannot be  committed if attempted, the entire transaction is abandoned (rolled back). Otherwise, the transaction is allowed to proceed and all resource managers are asked to commit.

A resource manager can be a database, for instance. Others examples includes a Message Service. The component which coordinates transactions is called Transaction manager.

Suppose you have an application *which involves two distincts databases*. How does Transaction manager performs its work by using Two phase commit protocol ?

1. Transaction Manager ask database 1 if it can commit the current transaction
2. If so, ask database 2 if it can commit the current transaction
3. Transaction Manager ask database 1 to commit
4. Transaction Manager ask database 2 to commit

Hibernate **is built on top of the JDBC API**. It just coordinates one database. So if you call

```
session.commit();
```

Behind the scenes, it call

```
connection.commit();
```

If you really want to study Transaction internals, my advice is [Java Transaction Processing](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/013035290X) book.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate has `TransactionFactory`:

> An abstract factory for Transaction instances. Concrete implementations are specified by hibernate.transaction.factory_class.

It has implementations: `JDBCTransactionFactory`, `JTATransactionFactory`, `CMTTransactionFactory`. These factories create an instance of `Transaction` - for example `JDBCTransaction`.

Then I can't tell you what happens for JTA and CMT, but for JDBC it's as simple as setting the auto-commit to false (when you call begin a transaction):

```
connection.setAutoCommit(false);
```

And respectively on `transaction.commit()`: `connection.commit()`

If any exception occurs when operating with the session, it invokes `connection.rollback()`

Comment: And how does this answer the OP's question?

Comment: @talonx the question was initially about hibernate. And my answer explains it - it shows _how_ transaction handling is implemented. And since EJB can use Hibernate as JPA provided, I think it's right. Which part you didn't like?

Comment: thanks for clarifying that. Maybe the OP has edited the question, because I don't see any reference to Hibernate - in which case it's not a question specific to Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Another good read would be the JTS articles by Brian Goetz; links:

1. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0305.html
2. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0410/index.html
3. http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtp0514.html